# SSO / Cross domain sign on with local access to user's data

Tags: php, mysql, yii, single-sign-on

I'm trying to create a cross domain sign in just like Google. So you have the same account for your youtube, gmail, google+, etc. However, there are several questions I'm confusing about:

Suppose I have 5 websites, I don't want to transfer any data about the user besides his/her **email, username and password**.  If I have only 1 user database instead of 5, every time I call the user database to access user's profile picture, username and etc, do I need to call the remote database?

I've been thinking about having a remote user and session database so every child site access that instead of local user and session database. But my application uses the table extensively and i'm worried about the performance of getting the data from a remote database every time.

How can I implement this in a clean way so every child site can easily access the user info locally, and they also share the same login/logout process just like Google and its products? (I'm using a PHP framework called Yii with MySQL)

---

I've come up with the following solution and I posted it as an answer as well, please advice if there is any issue about this? Thank you guys for help.

1. Have a user table in every child site, say child1.com & child2.com
2. Have a super user table in the parent site, say parent.com
3. When user logs into child1.com, check identity, redirect to parent.com/child1 to register or login. Once it's done, redirect back to child1 with an encrypted URL to login the user automatically. If the user's info has changed from the parent database, we can sync it here to the child database, (If it's a register process instead of a login process, write the user_id, username and email as well into the database so you can access this locally from child1.com)
4. When user logs into child2.com, it redirects to parent.com/child2, however, the users has been authenticated to parent1.com, so it redirects the user to child2 with out encrypted URL, so child2.com logs the user in directly.
5. For logout process, logout child1.com & curl other encrypted logout link to logout this user from other sites say child2.com or parent.com

Comment: what's the down vote about?

Comment: @jackhao: Most likely beacause your question is too broad. It just can not be answered. With Yii this will be a mixture of some logon remote service and session handling. Learn about Authorization and Authentication and also the differences between the two.

Comment: @hakre thanks. i've edited the question. One thing I'm worried about remote session handling or user database is that my application calls the user database a lot, will it be slow if i call it remotely every time? Do you mind check out my own answer underneath and give me some ideas?

Comment: @jackhao: The session is on the local server, don't mix that up. As written, learn about that first. Just some ground-work on your end. And hell, I can't say how slow or fast your server/database/users-computers are. That's something you need to find out for yourself *first*. You can't ask about it.

Comment: @jackhao: If you run into the problem later (I mean real problems), one way to deal with these is to authenticate against the main database but create a local profile. This can be synced on login (e.g. if it does not exists or if it changes). Additionally what Dagon suggested very early.

Comment: @hakre Sorry about the confusion. I was reading 2MAS's answer about storing a session table on the remote machine.  My solution now is having a local user database and a remote database as i wrote below.

Comment: Storing sessions in a remote database is most often counter-productive, as sessions are something near, so the storage of the session should be near, too.

Comment: @hakre Thanks for the advice. I think my solution is storing the session locally and remotely. So I'm actually logged into child1.com and parent.com, if i visit child2.com, i will be logged into 3, where session stored in all 3 sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking to a bunch of people, the following way seems promising.

1. Have a user table in every child site, say child1.com & child2.com
2. Have a super user table in the parent site, say parent.com
3. When user tries to log into child1.com,  redirect to parent.com/child1 to register or login. Once it's done, redirect back to child1 with an encrypted URL to login the user automatically. If the user's info has changed from the parent database, we can sync it here to the child database,  (If it's a register process instead of a login process, write the user_id, username and email into the database so you can access this locally from child1.com)
4. When user logs into child2.com, it redirects to parent.com/child2, however, the users has been authenticated to parent1.com, so it redirects the user to child2 without login again, and child2.com logs the user in directly with the encrypted URL from parent.com.
5. For logout process, say the user logout from child1.com, we curl other encrypted logout links automatically to logout this user from other sites say child2.com or parent.com

Comment: Lots of moving parts, lots of ways bugs can creep in, lots of surface area for penetration.  Not necessarily fatal to the implementation, but the design sounds fragile.  FWIW, StackExchange seems to do exactly what you're describing: perhaps you can inquire how it's implemented.

Comment: @bishop StackExchange won't share any of your user info and won't log you in, you can use the same email but you have to log in manually i think?

Comment: @bishop can you please point out some big issues?

Comment: Issues: difficulty in deploying user table schema changes to all sites while sites remain up. Discontinuity in user information/propogation of synched information, encryption/decryption strength, possibility of logout not propogating.  Re: SE, yeah, you're right; you have to log in manually and you want auto.  Not the same.

Comment: @bishop thanks for your help. Any possible solutions to these questions if we implement in other ways?

Comment: I would suggest what @gSorry said: implement the simplest, fewest moving parts functionality and don't worry about performance.  When you have a baseline implementation, then worry about performance.  My gut says simplest solution is OAuth.  If you don't want that, my gut says to expose an API on the master that lets you query & authenticate.  Then write a library that uses the API and sets a cookie, and that library also checks for the presence of said cookie to avoid many remote calls, and handles logout.

Answer (score 0):

Having a single remote database (parent server) with user information sounds like the simplest solution.

Keep in mind that PHP sessions are stored on a server's local file system, by default. So when you log into website-B with website-B's session data, you are not logged into any other sites.

This is where the magic happens. You need to instruct PHP to use the remote MySQL database to store session data, instead of the local machine's file system. Once set up, this works like magic.

I did a quick google, and found this site with instructions for setting up a MySQL session table for PHP. 
[enter link description here](http://phpsecurity.org/code/ch08-2)

Comment: Thanks. One thing I'm worried about remote session handling or user database is that my application calls the user database a lot, will it be slow if i call it remotely every time? Do you mind check out my own answer underneath and give me some ideas?

Comment: In your answer... If you are logged into child1, and then you visit child2, you wont be logged into child2 yet, because child2 doesn't know who you are yet. To identify yourself, you need to log into child2 first, which is what you don't want.

Comment: I will be logged into child2 because child2 will redirect me to parent.com, where I'm logged in already, and i will be redirected back to child2 with a login encrypted url to log me in.

Comment: Ok, I see. So you will go to the parent, and use the session data from there to tell child2 that you are logged in.

Comment: Ya that's what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit UserIdentity class ,find it in components folder, in each website and override authenticate() method to check OAuth, remote database, web service or what ever method you think it is comfortable for You... Don't worry about performance, because login is performed only once per session...

Comment: thanks for your help. I was worrying about that if I don't have a user table locally, every time i query the user database, i need to go remotely as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create something like this?

MasterSite.com

users

- id
- user_email
- password

sites

- name
- domain
- salt

site_users

- id
- user_id
- site_id

Child1.com

Say the user's name is Joe and has visits www.child1.com. He clicks on www.child1.com/register/. He will be redirected to www.mastersite.com/register/site/child1. After the registration he will be redirected back to www.child1.com/session_id/abcdefgh12345

Now say the user visits www.child2.com. And he visits www.child2.com/login/. The sysem will redirect him or popup a login back from www.mastersite.com/login/. If a session id already exists on www.mastersite.com then the user will be simply redirected back to www.child2.com/session_id/abcdefgh12345

That session id will be stored in the MasterSite.com's database and occasionally will be updated by www.childX.com as needed.

Storing user's data on each website is ok to a certain extent but it can get ugly real quick. However, since there are cloud based solutions nowadays... I don't think it will be much of a problem to scale the MasterSite's database or CPU power if the need arises.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I think we have similar solutions here..